# Creating Transparent Object, but Doesn't Reflect from Lighting in Render View?

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, shaders, edit-mode

So I made this transparent water and you can see through it like this, but when I look at the final render it doesn't shine from my light. Only that tiny part of the edge is light blue

[image]

If I choose the 3rd viewport option material preview it shows like this

[image]

How do I make my rendered preview look like my material preview?

I don't understand why my material preview is showing something completely different than my rendered even when I add lights?

Here's my nodes

[image]

Basically just added screen space refraction and also did the transparent on the rendered settings

Comment: in Material Preview there's a default HDRI background, maybe give your world an HDRI as well?

Comment: so I can't replicate an hdri with only adding lights manually? I'll try to add hdri and see

Comment: so the hdri solves the water issue, but now my entire world is super bright, so defeats the lighting effect I was trying to achieve. Is there an alternative to for a night time scene like a moon shining on the water at night? Also, in eevee the water is blue, but in cycles the surface turns gray?

Comment: the Rendered preview will take your lights and world HDRI into account, not the Material preview, so you probably need to lower down the lights strength, and also maybe lower down the world Background strength? As for the difference with Cycles, Cycles will treat the transparency differently (but also the lights, the environment...), so maybe you should first choose the render engine you plan to use...

Comment: oh I had my transmisson on 1 for my water so that's why is was colored gray even though the main color was blue